# Vector of multiple numeric types in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, vector

Is there an efficient way in C++11 to store multiple **numeric** types in a vector using `std::vector`? Most what I can find also store strings and what not. I just want to store signed and unsigned integers ranging from 8 to 32 bits.

So far I have come across `boost::variant` but that seems a bit of an overkill. Is there a neat trick I am missing out on? Or should I just go with boost?

I want to do something like this:

`std::vector<Numeric> v{(uint16_t) 1, (int32_t)-200};`

Comment: What will you do with the vector once you have it?

Comment: You could try to use `std::vector<boost::any>`

Comment: Why would boost::variant be overkill?

Comment: @AlanStokes I need to pass a large set of data to functions. Currently that's done with arguments. However, everytime I need to add one, change it's type or anything like that I have to change it in 5 places.

Comment: What is preventing you from storing everything in 32 or 64 bit integers?

Comment: How about writing a Numeric interface yourself? You could then implement a child class of that interface for each numeric type you want to handle

Comment: @Hedanito nothing, that's the next step. It's just a matter of time for now.

Comment: if you're going to end up storing all of your numeric values in a single type later then I wouldn't spend too much effort on this, because of what @chris-hayden pointed out in his answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. There is no generic numeric type in C++.

First, to handle your specific case: If you don't run out of memory, an `std::vector<std::int64_t>` will happily safe all your data and will be really fast. It is unlikely that you need anything else.

Otherwise:

If you need speed (i.e. after the generic solutions proof to slow), settle for a single type that does what you need as well as possible.

If speed is not that important (i.e. you cannot prove any significant disadvantage), the generic solutions like `boost.variant` and `boost.any` will serve you well.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamically sized containers in C++ are homogeneous, meaning that all of the elements in them must be of the same type.  If you want to emulate the storage of elements of different types in such a container then you will have to use a tagged union of some kind.  Boost.Variant, as mentioned, is one option.

On the other hand, if you don't need the container to resize dynamically you can use a heterogeneous container, like [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) or boost::tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> I just want to store signed and unsigned integers ranging from 8 to 32 bits.

You can use `std::vector<int64_t>` to store any number in that range. However, if you need to also know the size/type of the elements of the `vector`, you'll need to store more information.

You can use a `struct` that is something like:

```
struct MyNumber
{
    enum Type {INT8, UINT8, INT16, UINT16, INT32, UINT32};
    type type;
    uint64_t value;        
};
```

Then use a `std::vector<MyNumber>`.

To make conversions to and from `MyNumber`, you will need to add a bunch of constructors and other helper functions to `MyNumber`.